# Android Consumer IR Manager Must be one of:

Tags: java, android, eclipse, intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm trying to write an app to play around with my phone's IR blaster.

However, when I use any android SDK (I've tried IntelliJ, Android Studio, and Eclipse), I get "must be one of Context.SOMETHING" and that SOMETHING is a massive list of all things this call must be.

However, I do NOT see:
  **CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE**

like this link says I should: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/ConsumerIrManager.html

My code to do this is:

```
    activity.getSystemService("CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE");
```

And yes, before anybody asks, I'm trying to work with API 19, and to the best of my knowledge that is all set up properly. My emulator is running API 19, the manifest requires API 19, and so does the code above.

If it matters, I'm working on OS X 10.09, java 8. What should I do? Do you need more information from me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like an SDK bug.

Comment: That's a huge bummer, and I'm not totally sure that I buy it.... How are other people able to make such apps then?

Comment: Try using the string value `"consumer_ir"`, which is what `Context.CONSUMER_IR_SERVICE` maps to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it may be SDK bug, but you can ignore it.

CAMERA_SERVICE on Android L preview is same, IDE(android studio) still displays error on source editor, but gradle shows BUILD SUCCESSFUL.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually true. I just don't have it doing anything yet so I didn't think to try compiling! My OCD is going nuts at the little line under it, though ;)